# Typescript (React) function declaration correct but paramters show "any" type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, typescript-generics

I built a `Select` component in react that is fully typed and I now added a `multiple` prop to it, that will change the typing of the value and the `onChange` callback to be of type `Array<T>`
What the `multiple` prop does is it uses what I believe is called a Distributive Conditional to determine the type of both `value` and `onChange` of the Component's props like this:

```js
interface SelectBaseProps<T extends SelectValue = string> {
  options: SelectOption<T>[];
  placeholder?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  className?: string;
  searchable?: boolean;
}

export type SelectProps<T extends SelectValue, TMultiple extends boolean = false> = SelectBaseProps<T> &
  (TMultiple extends false
    ? {
        multiple?: TMultiple;
        value: T;
        onChange: (value: T) => void;
      }
    : {
        multiple?: TMultiple;
        value: T[];
        onChange: (value: T[]) => void;
      });
```

Where `SelectValue` just limits the values to be of type string or number for now.
I know, not the prettiest implementation but this is already after some iterations of debugging.
And then the select component itself is basically just

```js
export default function Select<T extends SelectValue, TMultiple extends boolean = false>(...) {...}
```

Now, on first sight this seems to work just fine! If I use this in a test component like this:

```js
function SelectTest() {
  const [val, setVal] = useState<string>();
  const options: SelectOption<string>[] = [
    { label: 'Option 1', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Option 2', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Option 3', value: '3' },
  ];

  return <>
      <Select value={val} options={options} onChange={(x) => console.log(x)} />
      {/* However, this works! */}
      <Select value={val} options={options} onChange={setVal} />
    </>;
}
```

and hover over the onChange prop, it clearly says that the prop of the onChange callback is of type string. If I change the code and make `value` be an array, the onChange value is also of type array. But for some reason, **the type is not infered in the function passed into the callback** and typescript complains that `Parameter 'x' implicitly has an 'any' type.`

So my question: Why is typescript not able to infer the type here, even though the function is typed correctly and can infer the type even for custom string types?

It could be related to my tsconfig configuration, so I added it in the reproduction stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-wuj3yu?file=Select.tsx,tsconfig.json

Comment: By the way, the issue also disappears when I explicitly set multiple={false}. So it must be the conditional preventing the type from being inferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-agwgkq?file=Select.tsx,App.tsx

I have to refuse of defining so many types/props:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

export type SelectValue = string | number | Array<string> | Array<number>;

type Unwrap<T> = T extends Array<infer R> ? R : T;

export interface SelectOption<T extends SelectValue> {
  label: string;
  value: Unwrap<T>;
}

interface SelectProps<T extends SelectValue> {
  options: SelectOption<T>[];
  value: T;
  onChange: (value: T) => void;
  placeholder?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  className?: string;
  searchable?: boolean;
}

export function Select<T extends SelectValue>(props: SelectProps<T>) {
  return <div>Dummy Select</div>;
}

...

import * as React from 'react';
import { Select } from './Select';
import './style.css';

export default function App() {
  const [val, setVal] = React.useState<string>('');
  const options = [
    { label: 'Option 1', value: '1' },
    { label: 'Option 2', value: '2' },
    { label: 'Option 3', value: '3' },
  ];
  const [multipleVal, setMultipleVal] = React.useState<Array<string>>([]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Select value={val} options={options} onChange={(x) => console.log(x)} /> // x is string
      {/* However, this works! */}
      <Select
        value={multipleVal}
        options={options}
        onChange={(x) => console.log(x)} // x is Array<string>
      />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Comment: Wow, sometimes the easiest option is the most simple one! I do have some problems with infering the SelectOption value type with the Unwrap type because for some reason things like Array.prototype.includes complain that the type is not narrow enough, but this is a great solution! Thank you!